# Spark how to determine number of partitions after groupby and agg

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What are the factors in determining how many partitions there are after a groupby and aggregation in Spark?

The following code snippet produces `1` partition after the aggregation (Spark 3.4.0). Will this always be the case?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    sum,
)

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("localapp")
    .getOrCreate()
)

columns = ["language", "user_count"]
data = [("Java", 1), ("Java", 2), ("Java", 3), ("Python", 1)]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df = df.repartition(200)
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) # 200

df = df.groupby("language").agg(sum("user_count"))
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions()) # 1
```

Thank you for any insight,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its 1 partition due to AQE (adaptive query execution) and its feature called shuffle partitions coalesce. You can disable AQE if you want to check the output without it:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", True)
```

I executed your code, with AQE i had one partition at the end with 280 kb and for records

Without AQE i had 1 partition with 3 record, 1 partition with 1 record and 198 empty partitions (due to default parallelism set to 200)

So in your case you have only one partitions because your input was really small a AQE was able to figure out that one partition is enough in this case